# TFVC SCM integration in SonarQube 6.0 is failing

Tags: sonarqube, tfvc

I am trying to get TFVC SCM plugin work with TFS 2015.
Version of SonarQube - 6.0

I am running an analysis using MSBuild Sonar Scanner with TFVC SCM plugin enabled.
However , while running the job I am encountering the following errors

**ERROR: IOException thrown in the TFVC annotate command : The pipe is being closed
ERROR: 
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at SonarSource.TfsAnnotate.Program.Main(String[] args)
Nov 25, 2016 6:04:08 AM com.google.common.io.Closeables close
WARNING: IOException thrown while closing Closeable.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed**

While searching for any probable resolution , I found out that it requires Team Explorer for VS 2013.
*https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d8b704ad-ffa7-44ca-a54f-1291af63358f/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftteamfoundationclient-version12000-cultureneutral?forum=vstest*

My Question is, that is there any way that we can make it work using Team Explorer 2015 as for me using Team Explorer 2013 is not possible.

Any suggestion/pointers will be really helpful here.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the Team Explorer but the TFVC plugin needs the TFS 2013 Object Model. You can download it here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VSCSReleases.TeamFoundationServer2013Update5ObjectModelInstalle

I had the same issue in a setup with TFS 2017 and a build agent that only had Visual Studio 2015 installed. After I installed the TFS 2013 Object Model on the build agent my build works fine.